# Style disabled form control with class

Tags: css, forms, input, css-selectors

I have an input button with a style, I want to alter the style if it is disabled.  This works when disabled is set like so `disabled="disabled"` but if disabled is set simply by writing `disabled` it doesn't work with the class specifier as well, am I constructing the CSS wrong?

So to clarify `input[disabled="disabled"].awesome` works properly, `input.awesome.disabled` does not.

I am testing with the following HTML:

```
<input class="awesome" disabled />
<input class="awesome" disabled="disabled" />
```

CSS:

```
input[disabled="disabled"].awesome , input.awesome.disabled
{
    color: #aaa;;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

If I write the selector like so, it works (but for all buttons)

```
input[disabled="disabled"], input.disabled { /**/ }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disabled is not a class (which is what your CSS implies), it's a pseudoclass. Use this:

`input.awesome:disabled`

Comment: This, and as a side note the attribute value does not need to be specified in the selector, for Boolean attributes like `disabled`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure :disabled is not a valid css pseudoclass... it is a pseudoclass in jQuery but not css. EDIT: [nope... nevermind...](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:disabled)

Comment: It's in the W3 documentation, so yes, it definitely is valid (although it doesn't work in IE8)